# restlet odata android client send cookie

Tags: android, forms-authentication, wcf-data-services, odata, restlet

I have a simple WCF Data Service and I am connecting to it on Android via the restlet odata extension. I'm trying to use Forms authentication with my WCF Data Service, which means including a authentication cookie, but I can't seem to see how to add a cookie to a org.restlet.ext.odata.Service. In my resetlet client service proxy constructor I've tried adding:

```
Request.getCurrent().getCookies().add("test","test");
```

I've also tried on my service proxy instance:

```
*myserviceinstance*.getLatestRequest().getCookies().add("test","test");
```

But nothing. I'm checking by adding a break point to 'OnStartProcessingRequest' in my WCF Data Service, but I never get the cookie.

Any help or direction is appreciated.